# Can a permanent Magic Mouth be used with new parameters after it has been discharged?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, magic-items, permanency

> A wizard casts *magic mouth*, permanently, on the door to his study.

Is the *magic mouth* then limited to its set parameters and message indefinitely, or could the caster set a new set of parameters for the magic mouth to respond to with a different message after it has been discharged?  Or anytime?

Answer (score 5):

The 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell [***magic mouth***](http://dndsrd.net/spellsMtoO.html#magic-mouth) [illus] (*Player's Handbook* 251) when made permanent by the 5th-level Sor/Wiz spell [***permanency***](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#permanency) [univ] (*PH* 259–60) should probably repeat the the identical message each time it is triggered, its [**Duration**](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#duration) essentially losing the phrase *until discharged*. This allows the effect to function long-term as a warning system. Until dispelled, it can then *both* warn denizens familiar with the effect of intruders *and* warn intruders of their impending grisly fates—which, in my experience, is typically what's desired from the spell anyway.

However, a level 10 or higher wizard who is willing to spend **1,000 XP** to make a *magic mouth* spell permanent should probably be allowed to have that effect function exactly as desired. With that in mind, if that wizard really wanted to have to reload the permanent *magic mouth* effect with a new statement every time after it triggers, this DM would be okay with such an arrangement instead, but that choice would've had to've been made when the *permanency* spell was applied.

Comment: Turing completeness ahoy!